# Estrutura de dados em c++

Tags: c++

Olá, quando aprendi C eu fiz várias bibliotecas, desde heaps, arvores binarias, listas, filas...etc

Gostava de saber se em C++ existem bibliotecas que podemos importar para utilizar de forma mais facil, como acontece com as bibliotecas `<string>` ou `<vector>`

Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

   string str1 = "Hello";
   string str2 = "World";
   string str3;
   int  len ;

   // copy str1 into str3
   str3 = str1;
   cout << "str3 : " << str3 << endl;

   // concatenates str1 and str2
   str3 = str1 + str2;
   cout << "str1 + str2 : " << str3 << endl;

   // total length of str3 after concatenation
   len = str3.size();
   cout << "str3.size() :  " << len << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Como importamos a biblioteca `<string>` permitiu que fosse mais facil manipular as strings.

Então queria saber se podemos dar import de como por exemplo `<heap>` e termos a estrutura de dados pronta a utilizar

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta resultaria em um reposta objetiva e curta

Comment: Gostava de saber se existem e possiveis exemplos de como aplicar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar as bibliotecas já existentes ao invés de criar as suas próprias, o ideal é consultar na [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) quais são as disponíveis.

Por outro lado, se você quiser criar a sua própria biblioteca, você pode criar arquivos que contém a sua estrutura de dados e arquivos de cabeçalho que as importem. Por exemplo, você pode criar um arquivo `heap.h` assim:

```
#ifndef HEADER_HEAP
#define HEADER_HEAP

typedef struct ALGUM_STRUCT {
    // Os campos do seu struct aqui.
} ALGUM_STRUCT;

class Heap {
    // Os campos, protótipos dos métodos, construtores e destrutores aqui.

    public:
        Heap();
        ~Heap();
        void inserir_valor(int valor);
};

ALGUM_STRUCT *criar_algum_struct();

void fazer_alguma_coisa(ALGUM_STRUCT *exemplo, char a, char b);

// Outros protótipos de funções aqui.

#endif
```

O arquivo de cabeçalho define suas `struct`s, classes, macros e funções, mas não inclui nelas as implementações, apenas as declarações e protótipos (exceto em alguns casos específicos).

Você implementa o heap em um arquivo `heap.c`:

```
#include "heap.h"

ALGUM_STRUCT *criar_algum_struct() {
    // blablabla
}

void fazer_alguma_coisa(ALGUM_STRUCT *exemplo, char a, char b) {
    // blablabla
}

Heap::Heap() {
    // blablabla
}

Heap::~Heap() {
    // blablabla
}

void Heap::inserir_valor(int valor) {
    // blablabla
}
```

E você pode utilizar o heap em algum outro lugar ao colocar o `#include`:

```
#include "heap.h"

void outra_funcao_que_usa_heap() {
    Heap h = Heap();
    h.inserir_heap(123);
    ALGUM_STRUCT *x = criar_algum_struct();
    // blablabla
}
```

Observe esse `#ifndef`, `#define` e `#endif` no `heap.h`. Servem para evitar que ocorra algum problema se o arquivo for por algum motivo incluído duas vezes.

Comment: Seu código tá mais pra C. Já existe [heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) em C++. Identificadores com duplo sublinhado (`__`) são [reservadores pela padronização](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797).

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Ficou melhor agora?

Comment: Utilizar `new` em C++ é má prática.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi E agora?

Answer (score 2):

Se voce analisar esse link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/
La fala sobre os containers da stl, e esses containers nada mais são do que o "uso" a implementação das estruturas de dados mais comuns como: filas, pilha, heaps, listas encadeadas, árvores binarias e por ai vai para resolver os mais variados tipos de problemas.
por exemplo: filas temos (std::queue), pilhas (std::stack), heaps (std::priority_queue), listas encadeadas (std::list), arvores binarias (std::set). Então voce pode sim incluir por exemplo:

```
#include <queue>
```

e estar usando todo o poder de uma std::queue , os métodos back, push, pop e por ai vai
espero ter ajudado.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/ é uma fonte mais confiável.